# Sharing Excel Sheet, One Row Per User

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm a teacher, and I use Excel to record student grades for my courses. Each row corresponds to a single student, and each column is the grade for a single assignment.

I would like to share the sheet with my students in such a way that each student is only able to view their own row. Ideally, this would be accomplished with a single sheet, so that I could a mass email with a single attachment. Less ideal, but still acceptable, would be a quick way to break up the single sheet by row into separate files, one per student. I would be receptive to any other creative ideas to efficiently accomplish this task (e.g., using something other than Excel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Mail Merge](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-mail-merge-to-create-and-send-bulk-mail-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705). This will allow you to send emails (do this through Word) that pulls information from a spreadsheet into placeholders ("merge fields"). You'll set up the spreadsheet with their email in one column and the information you wish them to see in the same row.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [RowShare](https://www.rowshare.com), it's a collaborative table.

It does exactly what you want: share a table where each user will see just his/her rows. You will still see the result as a single consolidated table. You even get alerts when it's modified and other nice additions.

There is a free and a Business version.

You can then edit the RowShare table in Excel to perform your standard mail merge.

**Disclaimer**: I work for RowShare.